# React Native Android In App Purchase Error

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

#### Version of react-native-iap

^2.4.1

#### Version of react-native

16.6.3

#### Platforms you faced the error (IOS or Android or both?)

Android

#### Expected behavior

Listing Items or Buying an Item

#### Actual behavior

Products Array is empty

#### Tested environment (Emulator? Real Device?)

Real Device

#### Steps to reproduce the behavior

I got two errors:
E_UNKNOWN An unknown or unexpected error has occured. Please try again later.
adding purchase listener is only provided in ios.
This is my Item's id: ozann_ozan

Some codes:

```
<TouchableOpacity 
                onPress={() => this.buyItem('ozann_ozan')}
                >
```

```
const itemSkus = Platform.select({
    ios: [
      'com.example.coins100'
    ],
    android: [
      'com.bettipspro'
    ]
  });
```

```
      componentWillMount() {
        this.getAvailablePurchases();
        this.getItems();
      }
```

```
async componentDidMount() {
      try {
        const products = await RNIap.getProducts(itemSkus);
        console.log(products);
        this.setState({ products });
      } catch(err) {
        console.warn(err); // standardized err.code and err.message available
      }
    }
    getItems = async() => {
      const products = await RNIap.getProducts(itemSkus);
      console.log(itemSkus);
      try {
        const products = await RNIap.getProducts(itemSkus);
        // const products = await RNIap.getSubscriptions(itemSkus);
        console.log('Products', products);
        this.setState({ productList: products });
      } catch (err) {
        console.warn(err.code, err.message);
      }
    }
    getAvailablePurchases = async() => {
        console.log('eben');
      try {
        console.info('Get available purchases (non-consumable or unconsumed consumable)');
        const purchases = await RNIap.getAvailablePurchases();
        console.info('Available purchases :: ', purchases);
        Alert.alert(purchases.length);
        if (purchases && purchases.length > 0) {
            Alert.alert('purchases.length');
          this.setState({
            availableItemsMessage: `Got ${purchases.length} items.`,
            receipt: purchases[0].transactionReceipt,
          });
        }
      } catch (err) {
        console.warn(err.code, err.message);
        Alert.alert(err.message);
      }
    }
    buyItem = async(sku) => {
      console.info('buyItem: ' + sku);
      try {
        const purchase: any = await RNIap.buyProduct(sku);
        this.setState({ receipt: purchase.transactionReceipt }, () => this.goToNext());
      } catch (err) {
        console.warn(err.code, err.message);
        const subscription = RNIap.addAdditionalSuccessPurchaseListenerIOS(async(purchase) => {
          this.setState({ receipt: purchase.transactionReceipt }, () => this.goToNext());
          subscription.remove();
        });
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue, and even though this is a bit old, I figured it would be useful to provide some support for those who have problems. As I just came across this problem myself and it was annoying as the documentation doesn't really mention this clearly.

On android Only - you need to **open a connection to the billing service**. This used to be `RNIAP.prepare()`, but it is now `RNIAP.initConnection()`. This does nothing on iOS but it is a required step for the `RNIAP.getProducts(itemSkus)` to work.

Also, if you are trying to receive **subscriptions**, for some reason it is agnostic on iOS and you get them if you call `RNIAP.getProducts(itemSkus)` but on android you need to specify them as subscriptions for it to work. You can do this with `RNIAP.getSubscriptions(itemSkus)`.

I was fighting with this for a couple of hours on Android and iOS for different issues, so I hope this helps.

Cheers

Comment: yes really thank you because you share your knowledge. I figured out this issue recently. Before I solved that, I used different library for android devices. Thank you again, it is really painfully and people can solve the issue because of your helpful answer.

Comment: What should the `RNIAP.initConnection()` return ? I'm getting an empty array when I'm calling this method.

Comment: `RNIAP.initConnection()` should give you true or false. This is form the doc : 
On Android this can be called to preload the connection to Play Services.
On iOS, it will simply call canMakePayments method and return value which is required for the listeners to work properly.